# How to get extra data in OnItemClickListener in Android?

Tags: android

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle programNum = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int progNum = programNum.getInt("Program");
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), hotelAct3.class);
    String hotelName = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

it should come from the activity that calls the list activity : 
such that i have an activity "hotelAct2.class" inside it i put extra data

public class hotelAct2 extends Activity {

```
EgyptDataSource datasource;
MySQLiteHelper sqlHelper;
ArrayAdapter<Hotel> hotelAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotelq2);
    Bundle programNum = getIntent().getExtras();
    final int progNum = programNum.getInt("Program");
    final String Srating = programNum.getString("Stars");
    //Intent ratingIntent = getIntent();
    //String Srating = ratingIntent.getStringExtra("Stars");

    Toast.makeText(hotelAct2.this, "The program is " + progNum + " The rating is " + Srating, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    RadioButton nileRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hRB2a);
    RadioButton pyramidsRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hRB2b);
    RadioButton downtownRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hRB2c);
    RadioButton letmeRB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hRB2d);

    if(Srating.equals("Five"))
    {
    nileRB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(hotelAct2.this, CairoHotelList.class);
            i.putExtra("RB", "nile5");
            i.putExtra("program", progNum);
            startActivity(i);
        }});
```

}
then it start the activity list which is "CairoHotelList.class" i want to get the extra data in the onItemClickListener of the activity class

the "progNum" returns 0 while it should return a number from 1 to 20, any help?

Comment: can you please include the code where you put the extra "Program" into the intent ?

Answer (score 0):

The `getIntent` method will return the intent that was used to start your current activity. It is completely unrelated to elements in an adapter, and that method will return the same value for every item you click on.

To clarify your question, where exactly should "progNum" come from?

Comment: it should come from the activity that calls the list activity :
such that i have an activity "hotelAct2.class"
inside it i put extra data 
Intent i = new Intent(hotelAct2.this, CairoHotelList.class);
    i.putExtra("program", progNum);
    startActivity(i);
then it start the activity list which is "CairoHotelList.class"
i want to get the extra data in the onItemClickListener of the activity class